# Adding scroll bar to my main window in python - tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning GUI programming with Python using Tkinter. I am beginner so please don't be rude on me.

I am having a problem with adding scroll bar to my main window.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests


def channelInfo():
   Link = link.get()
   r = requests.get(Link)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
   channelName = "Channel Name: " + soup.title.string
   firrt = Label(text=channelName,fg='yellow',bg='black').place(x=0,y=0)
   var = None
   var1 = None
   var3 = None
   var4 = None
   placer =0
   placer1 =0
   adjust = 0
   for i in soup.find_all('a',class_="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link  spf-link  yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2"):
       var = i.text
       second = Label(text=var,fg='black',bg='white').place(x=200,y=40+adjust)
       adjust+=20
   desc = soup.find_all(attrs={"name":"description"})
   DESC = desc[0]['content'].encode('utf-8')
   third = Label(text=DESC,fg='black',bg='yellow').place(x=0,y=20)
   for j in soup.find_all('li'):
         var1=j.text
         varr = re.findall('[0-9]+,[0-9]+ views',var1)
         for views in varr:
               var3 = Label(text=views,fg='blue').place(x=650,y=40+placer)
               placer+=20
   for k in soup.find_all('a',class_="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link  spf-link  yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2"):
      links = k.get("href")
      final = Link+links
      var4 = Label(text=final).place(x=750,y=40+placer1)
      placer1+=20



gui = Tk()
gui.geometry('500x400')
gui.title('The Youtube Crawler')
label = Label(text='Paste the link below to crawl Youtube',fg='blue')
label.pack()
link = StringVar()
entry = Entry(gui,textvariable=link)
entry.pack()
channel = Button(text='Crawl this channel',fg='white',bg='black',width=30,command=channelInfo)
channel.place(x=10,y=45)
'''
specific = Button(text='Inform about this video',fg='black',bg='white',width=30)
specific.place(x=270,y=45)
'''
entry.focus_set()
url = entry.get()
gui.mainloop()
```

This scraps the data and produces the output like this,

[image]

You can see that I can't scroll down or right to see all the data what I can do now?

What I have tried:

1. I tried adding the scroll bar using scroll bar function in placing x and y axis but the scroll bar is not working.

   scrollbar = Scrollbar(gui)
   scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill=Y )
   scrollbar.config( command = channelInfo)

instead the black screen is moving.

2. I referred google I found scrolled window and I could not grab those concepts since I am a beginner.

Kindly help me.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand - are you not permitted to use a scrollbar because your class hasn't covered it? If that is the case, you'll have to make some kind of "pages" functionality. If it isn't the case, use the scrollbar results you found via Google.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 No this is my first class they didn't teach me on creating Message boxes and separate windows. They just taught me To create main window and adding Labels. I am willing to be through in creating scroll bars in my main window instead of finding easy alternatives like scrolled window.

Answer (score 0):

Best practices for future reference, dont stick everything in your root window or Tk(), create widgets within it to manage your content, such as a Frame, Canvas, depending on what your needs are. This page provides most (if not all) the information you need on pythons Tkinter library http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/

Since your widgets are not organized, they are being added to your main window (almost randomly) once you pack them.

The scrollbar, as per effbot.org:

> When to use the Scrollbar Widget
>
> This widget is used to implement scrolled listboxes, canvases, and
>   text fields.

Amongst many other things, I currently see that in your code you do this:

```
third = Label(text=DESC,fg='black',bg='yellow').place(x=0,y=20)
label = Label(text='Paste the link below to crawl Youtube',fg='blue')
```

by doing this, your widgets are defaulting into the root window of your app, which should be avoided.

try creating a Frame and placing all your widgets inside it:

```
frame = Frame()
frame.pack()

label = Label(frame, text='Paste the link below to crawl Youtube',fg='blue')
entry = Entry(frame ,textvariable=link)
```

this will give you a better management of your created widgets, additionally, this should allow you to use the scrollbar as you intended